# Names of frames missing when printing form

Tags: excel, vba

I want to print a VBA form which contains several frames.
On the form there is a button to which a code has been added, which prints the form.
On the printout, the names of the frames are not included; what's wrong with the code?

The code used looks like this

```
Private Sub Udskriv_Click()
' Skift til det aktive ark
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

' Navn på Frame
Dim frameNavn As String
frameNavn = "Sammenstilling"

' Skift til formularen "Sammenstilling"
'UserForm_Sammenstilling.Show

' Gem skærmopdateringens aktuelle tilstand
Dim oldScreenUpdating As Boolean
oldScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating

' Deaktiver skærmopdatering for at fremskynde udskriften
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Print formularen
'UserForm_Sammenstilling.PrintForm
Sammenstilling.PrintForm

' Gendan skærmopdateringens tidligere tilstand
Application.ScreenUpdating = oldScreenUpdating

' Skift tilbage til det aktive ark
ws.Activate
End Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Captions on frames are not printed. A workaround is:

1. Put inside each frame a `Label` control containing the frame's caption you want to show when printed.
2. Set the `Top` property of the label to -50 which places the label out of sight in the frame.
3. In the function that is printing, before calling `Form.PrintForm`, set the label properties `.Top` and `.Left` to 0.
4. After calling the PrintForm function, set `.Top` back to -50

Like this:

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()

    With UserForm1
    
        '// Move the frame1 title for printing into the top left corner of the frame
        .Frame1Title.Top = 0
        .Frame1Title.Left = 0
    
    
        .PrintForm
    
    
        '// Move the frame1 title out of sight again
        .Frame1Title.Top = -50
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```